# Scrapy does not extract data

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to get some technical informations about automobiles from [this page](https://www.arabam.com/ilan/sahibinden-satilik-renault-megane-1-5-dci-icon/megane-renault-icon-full-kazasz-boyasiz-0-ayarnda-sahibinden/7887974)

Here is my current code:

```
import scrapy
import re
from arabamcom.items import ArabamcomItem
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class BasicSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name="arabamcom"
    allowed_domains=["arabam.com"]
    start_urls=['https://www.arabam.com/ikinci-el/otomobil']

    rules=(Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(r'/ilan')),callback="parse_item",follow=True),)

    def parse_item(self,response):
        item=ArabamcomItem()
        item['fiyat']=response.css('span.color-red.font-huge.bold::text').extract()
        item['marka']=response.css('p.color-black.bold.word-break.mb4::text').extract()
        item['yil']=response.xpath('//*[@id="js-hook-appendable-technicalPropertiesWrapper"]/div[2]/dl[1]/dd/span/text()').extract()
```

And this is my items.py file

```
import scrapy
class ArabamcomItem(scrapy.Item):
    fiyat=scrapy.Field()
    marka=scrapy.Field()
    yil=scrapy.Field()
```

When i run the code i can get data from 'marka' and 'fiyat' item but spider does not get anything for 'yil' attribute. Also other parts like 'Yakit Tipi','Vites Tipi' etc. How can i solve this problem ?

Comment: Unable to test this as I'm not at my computer but have you tried using the shell to debug this? Also I'm not familiar with the * syntax for xpath, can you try using the tag name instead?

Comment: what information do you want to scrap from the page specifically ? Please tell me because I don't understand the language used in this page. Just a guess, `yil` attribute is loaded dynamically so you can't locate it directly using Xpath.

Comment: @luiyezheng if this attribute is loaded dynamically you will have to use something like splash to render the page before scraping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## What's wrong:

**`//*[@id="js-hook-appendable-technicalPropertiesWrapper"]/......`**

- This id start with `js` and may be **dynamic** element appeded by javascript
- Scrapy do not have the ability to render javascript by default.

## There are 2 solutions you can try

- Scrapy-Splash

  > This is a javascript rendering engine for scrapy

  - [Install Splash as a Docker container](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash)
  - Modify your `settings.py` file to integrate splash (append following middlewares to your project)
        SPLASH_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8050'

    ```
    SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
        'scrapy_splash.SplashDeduplicateArgsMiddleware':100,
    }

    DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
        'scrapy_splash.SplashCookiesMiddleware':723,
        'scrapy_splash.SplashMiddleware': 725,
        'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware': 810,
    }
    ```
  - Replace your `Request` Function with `SplashRequest`

    ```
    from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest as SP
    SP(url=url, callback=parse, endpoint='render.html', args={'wait': 5})
    ```
- Selenium WebDriver

  > This is a browser automation-testing framework

  - Install Selenium from PyPi and install there corresponding driver(e.g. Firefox -> Geckodriver) to `PATH` folder
  - Append following middleware class to your project's `middleware.py` file:

    ```
    class SeleniumMiddleware(object):

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        middleware = cls()
        crawler.signals.connect(middleware.spider_opened, signals.spider_opened)
        crawler.signals.connect(middleware.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)
        return middleware

    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        request.meta['driver'] = self.driver
        self.driver.get(request.url)
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(2)

        body = to_bytes(self.driver.page_source)

        return HtmlResponse(self.driver.current_url, body=body, encoding='utf-8', request=request)

    def spider_opened(self, spider):
         """Change your browser mode here"""
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()


    def spider_closed(self, spider):
        self.driver.close()
    ```
  - Modify your `settings.py` file to integrate the Selenium middleware (append following middleware to your project and replace `yourproject` with your project name)

    ```
    DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
        'yourproject.middlewares.SeleniumMiddleware': 200
    }
    ```

### Comparison

- Scrapy-Splash

  - An official module by Scrapy Company
  - You can deploy splash instance to cloud, so that you will be able to browse the url in cloud then transfer the `render.html` back to your spider
  - It's slow
  - Splash container will stop if there is a memory leak. (Be sure to deploy splash instance on a high memory cloud instance)
- Selenium web driver

  - You have to have Firefox or Chrome with their corresponding automated-test-driver on your machine, unless you use PhantomJS.
  - You can't modify request headers directly with Selenium web driver

Answer (score 0):

You could render the webpage using a headless browser but this data can be easily extracted without it, try this:

```
import re
import ast
...

def parse_item(self,response):
    regex = re.compile('dataLayer.push\((\{.*\})\);', re.DOTALL)
    html_info = response.xpath('//script[contains(., "dataLayer.push")]').re_first(regex)
    data = ast.literal_eval(html_info)
    yield {'fiyat': data['CD_Fiyat'], 
           'marka': data['CD_marka'], 
           'yil': data['CD_yil']}
    # output an item with {'fiyat': '103500', 'marka': 'Renault', 'yil': '2017'}
```